# Bootstrap columns stacking vertically off center when they should lay side by side

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I am trying to do a very basic side by side of two columns on a master page. The body CSS on this specific master page is set to:

```
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

HTML:

```
<body id="exterior">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><p>VoiceShare by Bellybuds is a voice recording network that allows you to share your voice from wherever you are. Record a story, a song, a moment - right to the site. Or else invite others to join your network so they can share recordings with you. With a few simple clicks, messages can be downloaded to any MP3 player and share with the baby-to-be.</p></div>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

When I preview this in design view, the columns are stacking vertically and stretching the full width of the page. I'm obviously missing something, but I'm not seeing it.

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to view the layout in a browser instead of design view, design view cant handle all the crazy stuff that bootstrap alies to it classes, never trust design view. try go in a browser preview.

Comment: Bootstrap 2.3.2 would show changes in design view, so I assumed Bootstrap 3 would as well. This is going to make learning how to use 3 a tedious process.

Comment: Naah not really, u are never able to use the inbuild viwers, they are inacurate. you need to view it in your browers all the time its the only place they are right. Imagine you will start to use SASS or LESS one day, that will really make it hard for the design view, since it cant show unprocessed code. Good luck i hoped it helped :)

Comment: I agree with you, its just a lazy habit of mine I suppose.